# How to ORDER BY in this SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display this data selected as Facility and Name, with Name being in alphabetical order. but trying to add ORDER BY here is not allowing. How do you make here ORDER BY and the alpha order for the NAME ?

```
sqlSEQ = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_KEY DESC) AS RN,* From(Select distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " +
                    " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] , [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [VER], [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID " +
                    " FROM [VBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[SEQNO] = B.[SEQ_NO]   Left Outer Join VBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  " +
                    " Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) " +

                    " AND [VER] <> 'T1'  " +
                    sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")";
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: at the end after selected +

Comment: Add that attempt to our question so we can see what you've done wrong (my guess is you didn't add a space before the `ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlSEQ = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID_KEY DESC) AS RN,* From(Select distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " +
                    " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] , [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [VER], [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID " +
                    " FROM [VBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[SEQNO] = B.[SEQ_NO]   Left Outer Join VBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  " +
                    " Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) " +

                    " AND [VER] <> 'T1'  " +
                    sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")"
+ " ORDER BY [PATIENTNAME]";
```

Comment: rolf who would have known he meant patientname when he said facilityname

Comment: He just said NAME, I took the first one I saw in that inline heresy.

Comment: "Inline Heresy" - I think you just invented an indie rock band. :)

Comment: Or a domain name for anal DBAs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlSEQ = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER OVER () AS RN,* "+
         "From(Select distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, "+
         "[IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], "+
         "[PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " +
         " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] , "+
         "[PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [VER], "+
         " [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID " +
         "FROM [VBM].[T_CHARGES] A "+
         "LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[SEQNO] = B.[SEQ_NO] "+
         "Left Outer Join VBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  " +
         " Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) " +
         " AND [VER] <> 'T1'  " +
         sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")"+
         "ORDER BY ID_KEY, FACILITY_NAME";
```

or maybe just

```
  "ORDER BY FACILITY_NAME";
```

it is not clear from your question.

You don't need it in the row number column.